# Question Regarding a Value Being True, and then becoming False

Tags: python, time-series, conditional-statements, moving-average

Ok I'm a student and new to Python, bear with me. I'm  working with time series data and moving averages.

I want to write a conditional action that does something when a data point goes from True to False.

For example, when the series is above the moving average, wait until it's then below the moving average to dosomething()

However, I only want it to dosomething() if it changes from being above the moving average to going below it. I don't want it to dosomething() if it's just timeseries < the moving average.

so... I have:

```
 if self.series > moving_average:
            while True:
                if position < moving_average: #Need something if series then becomes less than the 
                                              #moving_average
                    self.dosomething('action', self.something)
                    break
                time.sleep(0.1)
```

I know this is ugly and I know the `while True:` and `if position < moving_average` is
at best incomplete. I need to know if I'm on the right track or if I have to do 
something completely different.

Thanks in advance

```
previous_series = df['series'].shift(1)   
previous_MA_35 = df['MA_35'].shift(1)

long_crossing = ((df['series'] < df[MA_35]) & (previos_series >= 
                                               previous_MA_35))

while True:
    if long_crossing = True:
        dosomething()
        break
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

Ok maybe that's a bit better. Still not sure if I'm on the right track though

Comment: position should be self.series

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is a variable which acts as state for your program.

```
state = False # False represents pos >= moving_avg, True represents pos < moving_avg

while True:
    new_state = False
    if pos < moving_avg:
        new_state = True

    move = (new_state and (not state) )
    # move is True only when new_state is True and state is False

    if move:
        do_something()

    state = new_state
```

Comment: Thank you, that's a great idea and makes sense. I'll test it out.